# Отправка e-mail с localhost'a

Tags: email, localhost

На ubuntu 12.04 стоит **sendmail**

Проблема в том, что при отправке e-maila через telnet письмо не доходит до почтового ящика, хотя в терминале все команды проходят без ошибок. Погуглив выяснил, что письма с локалхостов блокируются почтовиками! Как можно выйти из положения?

Comment: Amazon SES

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Вы пишете

    telnet localhost 25
    ....
    HELO localhost
    MAIL FROM: yournick@localhost
    RCPT TO: root@localhost
    DATA
    mail header lines
    \r\n
    message data
    .
    QUIT

так? 

Все ответы сервера 2хх, 3хх и  локальному root-у ничего не доходит?

Если нет, то объясните **конкретно**, что делаете.

Comment: Спасибо, локальному руту доходит, и все предыдущие доходили оказывается)))) 
А вот на мой почтовый ящик на yandexe и google нифига(

Comment: О вот и на яндекс пришло, только с задержкой в несколько минут + сразу в папку со спамом, хотя отправителем указал свой второй гугловский ящик

Comment: и в гугловский тоже пришли в папку Спам

Comment: @deniz, на самом деле MTA (это так почтовый сервер правильно зовется) часто проверяет соответствие IP, MX записи в DNS и в некоторых случаях адреса в MAIL FROM, а на текст в From: из заголовка письма не смотрит.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное можно начать с [SMTP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP), углубиться в раздел с RFC, но если вкратце, могу предположить, что обязательные требования к SMTP-серверу, как A- PTR- и MX- записи в [DNS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B8_DNS) не выполнены.

А ещё есть логи, там есть конкретные ошибки. Лучше там смотреть, чем гадать.

Comment: В логах ошибок не вижу, да и отправляется все только почему-то сразу в папку Спам

Comment: @deniz, Вы о каких логах говорите?

Comment: если отправляется в спам, может посмотреть на принимающей стороне? 

Тестовое письмо можно мне на admin@countrycom.ru?

Comment: Я логи Sendmail'a имею ввиду /var/log/mail.log

Comment: host75-27.snetfast.com?

Comment: я с локальной машины шлю, в файле hostname стоит mail.ru, а в host localhost и laptop, и в логе ничего подобного нет.

Comment: @deniz, Вы свою локальную машину назвали mail.ru?

А nslookup какие адреса для mail.ru выдает (в т.ч. для set type=mx)?

Comment: ну всё понятно.. отправляю вас к моему первоначальному посту про RFC по SMTP. Нужно прочитать, сделать усилие )) удачи

Comment: Да я переименовал в mail.ru, где-то прочитал про такой способ)))

Answer (score 1):

Нужно зарегистрироваться на почтовом сервере и завести там почтовый ящик. Настроить на своем хосте SMTP, указав адрес почтового сервера.